# Magento 2.3: $orderData->getShippingAddress() returns null

Tags: magento2.3, orders, shipping-address

I use Magento 2.3
If I want to access in view order page (on my account) shipping address, the result is null.

```
$orderId  = $block->getOrderId();
$orderData = $block->getOrderDetails($orderId);
$shippingAddress = $orderData->getShippingAddress();
```

`$shippingAddress` is null.
If I call `$orderData->getBillingAddress();` return the correct address.

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 public function getShippingAddress($orderId) {
        $order = $this->getOrderData($orderId);
        /* check order is not virtual */
        if(!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $orderShippingId = $order->getShippingAddressId();
            $address = $this->addressCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array($orderShippingId))->getFirstItem();
            return $address;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For detailed answer: [link](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-shipping-and-billing-address-from-order-in-magento-2/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20get%20Shipping%20and%20Billing%20address%20from%20Order%20in%20magento%202%3F,-In%20Magento%202&text=Call%20a%20required%20function%20in,get%20billing%20and%20shipping%20address.)